# Out of gas runtime error (Gas limit > Gas usage)

Tags: remix, gas, out-of-gas

I'm using remix to test out a particular contract method (both using the Javascript VM and a local blockchain via Ganache), and get this error for a specific contract method:

```
function withdrawAll() public payable {
    _totalSupply -= balances[msg.sender];
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;

    Withdrawal(msg.sender, this.balance);

    msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
}
```

Using the debugger I see that the execution stops on the `balances[msg.sender] = 0` line. The blockchain tells me that 27211 gas was a used, and that there is a `Runtime error: out of gas`.

Like I mention in the subject though – I provide a gas allowance much larger than this using remix, so I have no idea how to avoid this error. I have also played around with different gas allowances (both smaller and larger).

Comment: Many times, the network outputs the out of gas error as a generic error. You could ude the debugTraceTransaction in web3 to trace where it throws, and it could provide more help

Comment: I found that remix debugger sometimes will get confused when doing step by step trace. I see no evident error in your code but is not enough to try to reproduce it. Try commenting/uncommenting lines until you are sure where the error is. Perhaps some uninitialized storage data.